# I want to show firebase realtime data in flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase

This is the Firebase animated list code that I am using to show data :

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
                query: ref,
                itemBuilder: ((context, snapshot, animation, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.child('item-name').value.toString()),
                  );
                })),
```

But it is not showing anything from the Firebase.

I matched the item name from the Firebase documents it is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data using this function

```
DatabaseReference ref = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref(database path);
Stream<DatabaseEvent> stream = ref.onValue;

await stream.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
  var value = event.snapshot.value!;
  var data = json.encode(value);
  final parsedJson = jsonDecode(data.toString());
  
});
}
```

after that you can store parsedjson as a model or using as a object